# django model get all values with empty list

Tags: django, django-models

I need to filter results from db based on certain conditions. If a list of IDs where provided it should return values related to those IDs and if an empty list is provided it should return all the values.

Lets say a table has 5 rows of values, `Model.object.filter(id__in=[1,2])` should return values of ID 1 and 2.
And `Model.object.filter(id__in=[])` should return all the values.

Could this be done with single query or by chaining filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
k = [1,2]
if k:
  Model.object.filter(id__in=[1,2])
else:
  Model.object.all()
```

If you need to do in one query

```
from django.db.models import Q
 k = [1,2]
   if k:
        k_data = Q(id__in=k)
    else:
        k_data = Q(id__isnull=False)

    Model.objects.filter(k_data)
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. can this be done without condition?

Comment: @user11129319 i edited answer as per your requirement. If you get empty list another condition will execute to retrieve all data.

Comment: thanks a lot @Gorkhali Khadka. `filter(k)` should be `filter(k_data)`

Answer (score 1):

```
ids = [1,2]
ids_filter = dict()

if ids :
    ids_filter = {'id__in': ids}

Model.objects.filter(**ids_filter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a list type of variable, according to which you should query the database.

For Example:

```
id_list = [1,2]

if len(id_list) > 0:
    Model.objects.filter(id__in=id_list)
else:
    Model.objects.all()
```